# Taking an input and searching for a key word

Tags: python, python-3.x, diagnostics

i am trying to create a program which is a computer diagnostic service. I want to be able to ask the user what their problem is then extract key words from it. Then I want to print a solution. For example, the user says "My screen is broken", the program recognises "screen" and prints the solution for a broken screen. I honestly have no idea how to do this and i really need some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

with some dictionary of keywords to solutions `d`,

```
d = {'screen': 'Get a new screen', ...}
problem = input('What did you do? ').lower()
for k in d:
    if k in problem:
        print(d[k])
```

For each keyword, check if it's in the problem.  If it is, print the associated solution

Comment: how would i modify this code so that it read the keywords and solutions from a text file?

Comment: It's like: 'screen: get a new screen, speaker: ....... ' but every new keyword is on a new line. So speaker is down a line.

Comment: `with open('input.txt') as f: {k: v for k, v in map(lambda x: x.split(':'), f.readlines())}` Something like that should work. You might have to do some `strip`s if there's too much whitespace

Answer (score 0):

This works too

```
import re
D = {'screen': 1, 'keyboard': 2, 'mouse': 3}
keywords = set(D)
wordre = re.compile(r'\w+')

problem = "The cursor doesn't move on the screen when I move the mouse"
found = set(wordre.findall(problem.lower()))  & keywords
print(found) # prints {'mouse', 'screen'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't specify if your code will impose any limitations with regards to the extent of the user's input.

Assuming that the user will be able to describe his problem to a great extent (i.e input raw text as opposed to just typing a sentence or two) you can use the [summa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/summa) module.

If you take a look at its documentation, you will see that by applying its keywords function on any text; you can extract keywords out of it. Consequently, you can parse those arguments to print the respective solutions. A simple way to do this is to maintain a dictionary with your keywords of interest as keys and their solutions as values; and then just simply cross-check the summa generated keywords against these to print your final solution.

Comment: But its latest version is 0.0.7. This is a little frightening.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by frightening. Summa is the implementation of a (published) text-processing algorithm; so that counts towards its scientific credibility(to a certain extent at least). In this case, I don't think its version number has anything to do with whether this implementation is at its early stages and as a result not fully complete.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot reach summa's website.

Comment: @Gribouillis I think it works just fine now, if you still wanna take a look at it.